# Why is a prior distribution interpreted like this? [Rethinking Statistics book]

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics

In the Rethinking Statistics (2) book, on page 82, the McElreath describes the instantiation of a parameter:

$\mu$ ~ Normal(178, 20)

Interpreting this parameter is decribed as follows: The prior for $\mu$ is a broad Gaussian prior, centered on 178 cm, with 95% probability between 178cm +/- 40 cm.

My question is, how do we get 40cm if the std is 20? In other words, why isn't it 178 cm +/- 20cm?

Comment: 20 is the standard deviation, 95% of values are within $\pm 2$SD within the mean in a normal distribution, so $\pm40$ in this case. $\pm20$ would only enclose around 68% of the probability.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thank you!

Comment: The choice of a prior distribution can be somewhat arbitrary as one tries to find parameters of the prior family of distributions that fairly match ones prior information or opinion. So _exact_ computations are not always relevant. Here, however, exact computations may be useful: "What are quantiles .025 & .975 of $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=178,\sigma=20)"?$ Answer from R:  `qnorm(c(.0225,.975),148,20)` returns $107.9069$ and $187.1993.$ "What proportion of this dist'n lies btw 108 and 188"? Answ from R: `diff(pnorm(c(148-40, 148+40), 148, 20))` returns
$0.9544997 \approx 95\%.$

Comment: Highly relevant: [posts mentioning the 68-95-99.7 Rule](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=68+95+rule+score%3A5).